# In Python2 can I invoke super in __init__ (+ other methods) without params so that the super method is invoked w\ the same params as the given method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, init, super, superclass

I am programming in Python 2.7. In other languages like Ruby, there is an invocation of `super` in a method such that one does not need to specify the parameters with which to call `super` -- `super`. One omits the parameters in one's `super` call and the given super method is invoked with the same parameters as one's given method was called.

Here is an example from the StackOverflow question [Super keyword in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632224/super-keyword-in-ruby):

```rb
class Foo
  def baz(str)
    p 'parent with ' + str
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def baz(str)
    super
    p 'child with ' + str
  end
end

Bar.new.baz('test') # => 'parent with test' \ 'child with test'
```

As you can see the method `baz` in the `class` `Bar` contains the invocation of `super` without any parameters and the super method `baz` in the super class `Foo` *implicitly* gets called with the same parameter(s) as the method `baz` in the child class `Bar`

For a variety of reasons this is ***very*** convenient, and while obviously *implicit* behavior in programming has its drawbacks, it is really useful to be able to have an `__init__` method in a child class that does stuff in that child class and then invokes `__init__` via `super` without having to know the parameters for `__init__` in the super class.

Please help, any advice would be useful. I have been searching for an answer and unable to find one. I have seen many questions and answers on StackOverflow about `super` and `super` in `__init__` and `super` in Python, but nonw about whether there is syntax for calling `super` that does not require parameters to be specified and calls it with the same parameters as the given method was called in the child class.

What I am trying to do is very similar to `raise` in a `try`, `except`, `raise` construct in Python:

```py
try:
    linux_interaction()
except Exception as error:
    logger.critical(str(error))
    raise
```

In the above block I catch all exceptions, I log any exception as critical and then I throw it with just a call to `raise`, no parameters. That calling syntax of `raise` with no parameters causes the exception that was caught in the variable named `error` to be thrown and preserves the calling stack/stack trace. If one called `raise error` instead of just `raise`, then the stack trace from where the `error` originated would be lost.

I am trying to do something similar here, just invoke `super` and get the super method invoked with the same parameters as the given method without needing to know what they are and without needing to specify them -- that would be convenient, right?

Anyone know if this is possible and if so what the syntax in Python 2.7 would be?

Comment: No, you can't do this in Python. `super()` is just a way of finding and binding a method from another class in the MRO, and from there it is just a normal function call, just like any other.

Comment: Write a wrapper function, then apply it with a decorator? You have to hard-code the current class name regardless.

Comment: The short answer is: no, you need to provide arguments to `super` in Python 2. Python's `super` is, as far as I can tell, far more general than the Ruby keyword; it was designed to support multiple inheritance, which Ruby does not support.

Comment: I tried throwing something together, but 1. it's impossible to name the current class before its definition, so it is also required to use a class decorator and metaclass, 2. `inspect.Signature` doesn't exist in python2 and I'm too lazy to look for the backport, and 3. even in python3 `__class__` isn't usable at class-scope, only at method scope, so a metaclass is probably the only reasonable approach.