# After upgrading to Ruby 3, unable to pass multiple arguments to my "initialize" method

Tags: initialization, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-3

I recently upgraded to Rails 6 with Ruby 3.  I have this in a controller

```
my_object = MyObject.new(my_object_params, @header)
```

The object “initialize” method is defined like so

```
  def initialize(params, header)
    super(params)
    user&.header = header
  end
```

But now when attempting to initialize the object, I get the error

```
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
```

What’s the proper way in Ruby 3 to pass multiple arguments to an object during initialization?

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace?

Comment: from which class are you inheriting?  could it be its constructor doesn't accept parameters at all?  maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632224/super-keyword-in-ruby) will help

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this way:

```
  def initialize(params, header)
    super(**params) #Note that you need to splat out the params!
    user&.header = header
  end
```